# MIME type mismatch

Tags: html, css

I cannot resolve the error with css:

> The resource from “http://localhost:63342/static/style.css” was
> blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch
> (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

The folders structure is:

```
root
|-> content
-| index.html
|-> static
-| style.css
-| script.js
```

In index.html I import the stylesheet:

```
<link href="../static/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

But it results in the above error in the console. The error claims that my type is 'text/html'?

My css file:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
}

.section {
    display: none;
    margin-top:40px;
    border-top:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

What might be a problem?

I import the js script in similar way and it works fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/jct.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The response header should contain "text/css" instead "text/html":

```
Content-Type: "text/css"
```

Try to use:

```
<link type="text/css" href="../static/style.css">
```

What server are you using?